# How to stretch the image of (1* 66 ) pixel

Tags: wpf, image, stretch

In a WPF Application using XAML,

I have 2 images, which needs to be oriented horizontally. One is of width 784 * 66 and other is 1 * 66.

while, design time, since my window is auto it shows properly, but during runtime, the window is of 1280 width... so, the image 1 * 66 should stretch and cover the rest (1280 - (784 + 1))

|________________________________|_|

should become

|________________________________|___________________________|

which means , my firstimage should have the same width (784) and the second image should stretch to cover the rest even though its only one pixel.

Please help me

```
     <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="66" Name="grdTopImages">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="1" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="66" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Name="imgClientPhoto"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="/Honeywell.eHTMP;component/Resources/_left.gif"></Image>
                <Image Name="imgExtraImg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Honeywell.eHTMP;component/Resources/_right.gif"></Image>
            </Grid>
```

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your column definitions the wrong way around. Should be:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
```

This means the first column is as big as it needs to be, and the second column takes up whatever's left.